# How to check whether MongoDB is running from a shell script?

Tags: mongodb, shell, cron

Here is the shell script that I am using to check MongoDB's status. `checkmongo.sh` through a cron job every two minutes.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "shell script called"
if pgrep mongo > /dev/null
then
    echo "MongoDB Running"
else
    echo "Stopped .. starting MongoDB"
        sudo service mongodb start
fi
```

Cron job is as follows :

```
*/2 * * * * /etc/init.d/checkmongo.sh> /etc/init.d/cronjob.log 2>&1
```

No matter MongoDb is running or not `cronjob.log` always has the content as "MongoDB Running". What am I doing wrong ? Please help. Thanks

Comment: check your mongodb log and see what's there. Probably it might be terminating for some reason.

Comment: @Saleem The problem is if I run the shell script from the terminal everything works fine. The problem occurs only when I do it through the cron job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vinay,

A couple of things:

1 -- Do you want to check if MongoDB is running or do you want to check if it is responding to queries?

Your current design will only tell if there is a process whose name includes the word "mongo" running.
I would design a "canary query" that you can run with the mongo shell and use  the result to determine if MongoDB is running or not. So in the rare case where MongoDB daemon might be running  but not responsive you could be alerted.

2 --Your process is checking for the word "mongo", the executable for the mongoDB database is "mongod".

Your script is called "checkmongo". Every time you script runs there is a "checkmongo" process running and the if conditions will always be true. The script is detecting itself instead of the mongod process.

Change your search condition to mongod

> if pgrep mongod > /dev/null

Comment: Yes, I want to know whether MongoDB is running or not. And, if it has stopped I want to start it automatically.
I am sure there are no other processes which have the word "mongo" in their name.

Comment: Vinay according to your question the name of your script contains the word mongo.  Is your script called "checkmongo.sh" ?  Check for "mongod" in your if condition will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

mongod_status=`service mongod status`
echo "${mongod_status}"

if [[ "${mongod_status}" == *"start/running"* ]]
then
    echo "MongoDB is already running."
else
    sudo service mongod start
    echo "Start MongoDB."
fi
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)